# Does a Java Endpoints class need a Primary Key field?

Tags: java, google-app-engine, google-cloud-endpoints

Does Endpoints (Java) require a persistable class to have an id field?

Before endpoints, my JDO model itself did not have an id (primary key) field.  Datastore has its own id field, and it generated a value upon inserting a new record.  The model works, and I could insert records (with datastore successfully inserting and generating an id value).

I converted it to Endpoints (using Google Plugin for Eclipse), and made slight adjustments.  The generated code is referencing an id that's not in the model.  So I switched the parameter to another unique identifier (email address).

It compiles and deploys.  But when I run API explorer, I can't insert.  I'm getting "The class [class name] is not persistable."

But when I put an id field as primary key, now my inserts are asking for a value in id (which is not ideal for my situation).

Does endpoints require a class to have an id (unique identifier)?  If so, is there a way to make appengine/datastore generate it for me?  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

My assumption is yes, all such persistable classes need an id field. I add mine via Objetify with `@Id`. [Here](https://code.google.com/p/objectify-appengine/wiki/Entities#The_Basics) is the relevant documentation, also about autogenerating ids:

> - Entities must have have one field annotated with `@Id`. The actual
>     name of the field is irrelevant and can be renamed at any time, even
>     after data is persisted. This value (along with the kind 'Car')
>     becomes part of the Key which identifies an entity.
> - The `@Id` field can be of type `Long`, `long`, or `String`. If you use
>     `Long` and save an entity with a `null` id, a numeric value will be
>     generated for you using the standard GAE allocator for this kind. If
>     you use `String` or the primitive `long` type, values will never be
>     autogenerated.